# How to remove image elements from string that has specific alt= value?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains HTML image elements that is stored in a var.
I want to remove those image elements that has alt="today" and leave the rest of images untouched .

```
<img src="./images/ok.gif" alt="today" />
```

I have tried:

```
var replaced2 = content.replace(/\<img src="./images/ok.gif" alt="today" />\/g,'');
```

but had no luck.
Can anyone help me out at all?
Thanks

Comment: Better to use the DOM for this...

Comment: easiest way is select all images with jquery and use each to loop through all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your regular expression:

```
/<img src=".\/images\/ok.gif" alt="today" \/>/g
```

Gotta make sure to escape any forward slashes because they denote a regexp

```
/<regexp syntax>/
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a RegExp:

```
var replaced2 = content.replace('<img src="./images/ok.gif" alt="today" />','');
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wm4SQ/)

Comment: thanks all for reply. your solution only removes the first image element but not the rest. I got 5 to remove in the big string! how to remove all of them?

Comment: Ah for that you need a RegExp like m1 suggested. Glad you found your answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

what you need to look into is: JavaScript RegExp